# Create a split figure using subfigures

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I am designing an inset:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[item A]{%                                                                                                                                                                                      
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \caption{Figure caption}
  \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    data a & data b\\
    11     & 22
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{table showing values in item A}
  \label{table:mytable}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[item B]{%                                                                                                                                                                                      
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
  \subfloat[item C]{%                                                                                                                                                                                      
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
  \caption{Figure caption}
  \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Figure 2 is planned as a direct continuation of Figure 1 (the table in between displaying values in Figure 1). Therefore Figure 2 should be numbered Figure 1, and the subfigure numbering should start from `b)`. How to best design such a split figure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is what you want

[image]

This is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[item A]{%                                                                                                                                                                                      
  \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \caption{Figure caption}
  \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    data a & data b\\
    11     & 22
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{table showing values in item A}
  \label{table:mytable}
\end{table}

 \addtocounter{figure}{-1}    %<<<<<<
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[item B]{%      
    \addtocounter{subfigure}{1} % <<<<< here                                                                                                                                                                                
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}
  \subfloat[item C]{%                                                                                                                                                                                      
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
  \caption{Figure caption}
  \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I guess you should remove the first `\caption{Figure caption}`. In this case also

`\addtocounter{figure}{-1}    %<<<<<<`

[image: cc2]

Comment: yes, this is the indended result.

Answer (score 4):

This variation uses the subcapton package instead of subfig.  Actually, my original goal was to use `\ContinuedFloat`, but the table prevents that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[item A]{\includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \caption{Figure caption}
  \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    data a & data b\\
    11     & 22
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{table showing values in item A}
  \label{table:mytable}
\end{table}

\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  {\setcaptionsubtype\stepcounter{subfigure}}% group
  \subfloat[item B]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-b}}%
  \subfloat[item C]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}}
  \caption{Figure caption}
  \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```